# Append rows to dataframe, add new columns if not exist

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like below which

```
>>df
  group  sub_group    max
0     A          1   30.0
1     B          1  300.0
2     B          2    3.0
3     A          2    2.0
```

I need to have group and sub_group as atrributes (columns) and max as row
So I do

```
>>> newdf.set_index(['group','sub_group']).T
group         A      B         A
sub_group     1      1    2    2
max        30.0  300.0  3.0  2.0
```

This gives me my intended formatting

Now I need to merge it to another similar dataframe say

```
>>df2
  group  sub_group    max
0     C          1   3000.0
1     A          1   4000.0
```

Such that my merge results in

```
group         A      B         A     C
sub_group     1      1    2    2     1
max        30.0   300.0  3.0  2.0    NaN
max      4000.0    NaN   NaN  NaN    3000.0
```

Basically at every new df we are placing values under appropriate heading, if there is a new group or subgroup we add it the larger df. I am not sure if my way of transposing and then trying to merge append is a good approach

Since these df are generated in loop (loop items being dates), I would like to get a way to replace `max` printed in 1st column(of expected op) by loop date.

```
dates=['20170525', '20170623', '20170726']

for date in dates:
     df = pd.read_csv()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add parameter `index_col` to `read_csv` first for `Multiindex` from first and second column:

```
dfs = []
for date in dates:
     df = pd.read_csv('name', index_col=[0,1]) 
     dfs.append(df)

#another test df was added
print (df3)
                    max
group sub_group        
D     1          3000.0
E     1          4000.0
```

Then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) them together with parameter `keys` by `list`, then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and transpose:

```
#dfs = [df,df2,df3]
dates=['20170525', '20170623', '20170726']
df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=dates)['max'].unstack(0).T
print (df)
group           A           B            C       D       E
sub_group       1    2      1    2       1       1       1
20170525     30.0  2.0  300.0  3.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
20170623   4000.0  NaN    NaN  NaN  3000.0     NaN     NaN
20170726      NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN  3000.0  4000.0
```

Comment: I wonder if I made my question clear. Each new df entry is to come in new row. Like you see 2 rows in my expected output.

Comment: Yes, maybe i am wrong. So I think you need append all dataframes together and then if multiple rows per same groups onlyneed max value per group. Am I wrong?

Comment: max is just a column name. we dont need to calculate max anytime ! We just get group and subgroup and some value (called max, dont go by name). Everytime new df comes , we just need to append values from a column (called max) . If there is already such a group sub_group just put value beneath it. else create new column of group and sub_group

Comment: Thank you, I change solution completely. can you check it?

Comment: i have a small doubt df,df2,df3 I should first add to dfs list right ? then do a `for i in dfs: maindf = pd.concat(maindf,i)` basically I'm missing the concat part (I get 1 df at a time in loop) I cannot wite  pd.concat([df,df2,df3], keys=dates)['max'].unstack(0).T since there are many df each coming by for loop

Comment: I try edit answer, but basically `[df1,df2,df3]` is same as `dfs`.

Comment: getting ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Yes, there is problem with `unstack`. There are multiple values per group. Give me some time for solution.

Comment: sure i wait for your response :)

Comment: So there is problem duplicates per group. so if use `df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=dates)['max']` and then `print (df[df.reset_index().duplicated(['level_0','group','sub_group'], keep=False).values])` get all duplicates pairs `groups` with `subgroups`. What next? Remove dupes (if duplicates let only first or last value, all another drop)? Aggregate dupes (e.g. if 100, 50, 200 are duplicates create mean of them by `(10+50+200)/3`)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150299/discussion-between-pythonrcpp-and-jezrael).